# Async ADO.NET or TaskFactory

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I've 4 heavy database tables (30 million rows each) and my query gets data from all 4 tables and do the union to combine all and query is not returning many rows (up to 1000). So let's say the whole query is taking 20 seconds to complete, I'm thinking to write a separate query for each table and call them using async or TPL and then combine the results in my business object (c# .Net 4.0) and then return to ASP.NET web form.

I've looked at BeginExecuteReader and Task.Factory.StartNew but I'm not sure how to put everything together, has anyone done something like this before? Any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've finally done this myself and putting it here if someone else need it.

```
DataTable dtReturn = new DataTable();
var connection = new SqlConnection((_connectionstring.IndexOf("MultipleActiveResultsets") == -1) ? _connectionstring + "MultipleActiveResultsets=True;" : _connectionstring);
try
{
    connection.Open();

    Task<DataTable>[] tasks = new Task<DataTable>[source.Rows.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        int s = Convert.ToInt32(source.Rows[i][0]);
        Task<DataTable> t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = commandText;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandTimeout = timeout;

            foreach (SqlParameter p in parms)
            {
                if (p.ParameterName == "@Sources")
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured, ParameterName = p.ParameterName, Value = s.ToString().ToIDList() });
                else
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = p.ParameterName, Value = p.Value });
            }
            var dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            command.Parameters.Clear();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                dt.Load(dr);
                dr.Close();
            }
            return dt;
        });
        tasks[i] = t;
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    if (tasks.Length > 0)
    {
        bool isSchemaCloned = false;
        foreach (var t in tasks)
        {
            if (!isSchemaCloned && t.Result.Columns.Count > 0 )
            {
                dtReturn = t.Result.Clone();
                isSchemaCloned = true; 
            }

            foreach (DataRow r in t.Result.Rows)
            {
                dtReturn.Rows.Add(r.ItemArray);
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
        connection.Close();
}

return dtReturn;
```